# /tmp/workdir@tmp/durable-2169cc7c/script.sh: 1: /zap/zap-full-scan.py: not found

Tags: jenkins, owasp, zap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sonlY.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM9iv.png
I am provisioning an OWASP using Jenkins integration but I am facing this issue.
I provisioned using docker image. it seems the ".py file is missing". The requirement is to run OWASP zap through JENKINS not locally

Comment: Whos Docker image are you using? If its a ZAP one, which one? What do you get if you run `ls -l /zap/` ?

Comment: I am using this from dockerhub owasp/zap2docker-stable

Comment: Here is my settings under jenkins job:

Comment: I am using this one. owasp/zap2docker-stable.

Answer (score 1):

I've just pulled the latest docker image and run `docker run -i -t owasp/zap2docker-stable ls -l /zap/` (as suggested in my comment). The output was:

```
total 5648
-rw-r--r-- 1 zap zap    5930 Aug  1 08:18 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 zap zap    2211 Jan  2  1970 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 zap zap      18 Aug  1 08:20 container
drwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap    4096 Aug  1 08:18 db
drwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap    4096 Aug  1 08:18 lang
drwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap    4096 Aug  1 08:18 lib
drwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap    4096 Aug  1 08:18 license
drwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap    4096 Aug  1 08:19 plugin
drwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap    4096 Aug  1 08:18 scripts
drwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap    4096 Aug  1 08:20 webswing
drwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap    4096 Aug  1 08:18 xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 zap zap 5480951 Jan  2  1970 zap-2.11.1.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap   25720 Aug  1 08:18 zap-api-scan.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap   24796 Aug  1 08:18 zap-baseline.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap   20237 Aug  1 08:18 zap-full-scan.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap    2803 Aug  1 08:18 zap-webswing.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap     213 Aug  1 08:18 zap-x.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 zap zap     200 Jan  2  1970 zap.bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 zap zap  123778 Jan  2  1970 zap.ico
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zap zap    4175 Jan  2  1970 zap.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 zap zap   23189 Aug  1 08:18 zap_common.py
```

When I run `docker run -i -t owasp/zap2docker-stable  /zap/zap-full-scan.py` the script runs and I get the standard usage message, so the script is clearly in the image.